# strong advocate on vs strong advocate of

Tags: software, prepositions

I have the following sentence:
I am a developer, thinker, and a strong advocate on micro-services, architecture and development of blah blah

> I am a strong advocate ON

Or should it be:

> I am a strong advocate OF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are an advocate *of* something. Sometimes you'll hear "I'm an advocate *for* something," but "advocate *on*" is never used. Depending on the context, you could also use the verb: "I advocate micro-services, architecture and development ..."

Comment: I could see "advocate on" being used with an explicit (or even implicit) "the subject of".  "I am an advocate on the subject of *[thing]*."  Though it does rather sound like the speaker is trying to avoid saying whether he advocates *for* or *against* the thing.

Answer (score 1):

A 'strong advocate on' can be used where 'on the issue of' is implied: 'a strong advocate on human rights' for example, however, it's mostly better to use 'advocate of'.